# Google Tag Manager Advanced Data Layer Integration

Tags: magento2, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am using the https://github.com/magepal/magento2-google-tag-manager extension for GTM Data Layer integration. But unfortunately I am not able to capture data on Google Analytics.

I have just installed the extension and added configurations in the admin. It is showing in Google Tag Assistant (Chrome Extension) that I have Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager tags on the web page. Which is correct. But I am not getting dataLayer tab and no event is fired.

Can someone tell what am I missing here? Could there be any conflict with any other extension?

Expected Result: dataLayer should be integrated after installing the above extension
Actual Result: No dataLayer is passed :(

Looking for recommendations and experienced feedback if anyone has faced similar problem

Using Magento 2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue by using [this free plugin](https://www.weltpixel.com/google-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce-tag-manager-magento-2.html)

This also provides additional data to Google Analytics like addToCart, removeFromCart, etc

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: But it is not working with GA4 especially the purchase event

Comment: This is an old extension before GA4 was released